# How to read integers from a file that are 24bit and little endian using Python?

Tags: python, file-io, endianness

Is there an easy way to read these integers in? I'd prefer a built in method, but I assume it is possible to do with some bit operations.
Cheers

**edit**
I thought of another way to do it that is different to the ways below and in my opinion is clearer. It pads with zeros at the other end, then shifts the result. No if required because shifting fills with whatever the msb is initially.

```
struct.unpack('<i','\0'+ bytes)[0] >> 8
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Python's `struct` module lets you interpret bytes as different kinds of data structure, with control over endianness.

If you read a single three-byte number from the file, you can convert it thus:

```
struct.unpack('<I', bytes + '\0')
```

The module doesn't appear to support 24-bit words, hence the `'\0'`-padding.

EDIT: Signed numbers are trickier. You can copy the high-bit, and set the high bit to zero because it moves to the highest place of 4 bytes (the last `\xff` has it).:

```
struct.unpack('<i', bytes + ('\0' if bytes[2] < '\x80' else '\xff'))
```

Or, for python3 (`bytes` is a reserved word, checking a byte of a byte array gives an `int`):

```
struct.unpack('<i', chunk + ('\0' if chunk[2] < 128 else '\xff'))
```

Comment: Thanks, but I forgot to say that they are signed so padding the most significant bits will not work, as fair as my limited understanding of two's complement goes.

Comment: @jolly: I've amended my answer accordingly.

Comment: @John: Silly me. Thanks for the improvement.

Answer (score 11):

Are your 24-bit integers signed or unsigned? Bigendian or littleendian?

```
struct.unpack('<I', bytes + '\x00')[0] # unsigned littleendian
struct.unpack('>I', '\x00' + bytes)[0] # unsigned bigendian
```

Signed is a little more complicated ... get the unsigned value as above, then do this:

```
signed = unsigned if not (unsigned & 0x800000) else unsigned - 0x1000000
```

Comment: Sorry mate, didn't see you there below the fold. Apparently I don't have enough reputation to upvote but thanks for the effort!

Answer (score 4):

If you don't mind using an external library then my [bitstring](http://python-bitstring.googlecode.com) module could be helpful here.

```
from bitstring import ConstBitStream
s = ConstBitStream(filename='some_file')
a = s.read('uintle:24')
```

This reads in the first 24 bits and interprets it as an unsigned little-endian integer. After the read `s.pos` is set to 24 (the bit position in the stream), so you can then read more. For example if you wanted to get a list of the next 10 signed integers you could use

```
l = s.readlist('10*intle:24')
```

or if you prefer you could just use slices and properties and not bother with reads:

```
a = s[0:24].uintle
```

Another alternative  if you already have the 3 bytes of data from you file is just to create and interpret:

```
a = ConstBitStream(bytes=b'abc').uintle
```

Comment: I'd prefer not to use an external library for this particular project, but I'll check it out nonetheless. What is performance like for something like this? They will potentially be coming in at around 3Mb/s, so 130,000 of them every second. Frankly the sample rate is far higher than necessary so I can just discard the majority of them, but if I don't will this library manage?

Comment: @jolly: If performance is a concern then you should stick with the `struct` method. Bitstring is (for now) pure Python so it won't beat this. It's reasonably efficient but the emphasis has been on making bitwise tasks as easy as possible, not as fast as possible - at least not yet :)

Answer (score 3):

### Python 3 Method

In Python 3 I prefer using [`int.from_bytes()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#additional-methods-on-integer-types) to convert a 3 byte representation into a 32 bit integer. No padding needed.

```
value = int.from_bytes(input_data[0:3],'big',signed=True)
```

or just

```
value = int.from_bytes(input_data)
```

If your array is only 3 bytes and representation is default.

Answer (score 2):

A bit late, but here's something that could be useful in this situation. It builds on the OP's updated answer, but integrates it into a function that reads out a whole list of values from a packed file of 24 bit ints.  It does it mostly with struct, so I think it should be reasonably fast.

```
  def int24_to_int(self, input_data):
    bytelen = len(input_data)
    frames = bytelen/3
    triads = struct.Struct('3s' * frames)
    int4byte = struct.Struct('<i')
    result = [int4byte.unpack('\0' + i)[0] >> 8 for i in triads.unpack(input_data)]
    return result
```